# Create multiple text files from excel rows

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I have a list of different values in Column A that I'd like to extract and paste into a text file. But the text file contains a structured format and I'm not sure if this is doable through VBA.

[Excel Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpl7U.png)

So for each row from Column A, I want to assign those values into the "XXX" field in the text file below. The order should be consistent whereas the first "XXX" is values from A2; second "XXX" is values from A3; third "XXX" is values from A4; and so on.

[Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zcrh.png)

I have little to no VBA experience so any input would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are plenty of previous posts here on creating a text file from Excel VBA - try modifying one of there and post back with your code if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: After reading your question, I think your title is misleading. You are not trying to "Create multiple text files" you are trying to replace multiple values inside a single text file. Am I understanding your quesiton correctly?